# why does "desktop" show on my mobile app for "device category" in firebase?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-analytics

When looking at my mobile app data in Google Analytica Firebase. I'm wondering why web would show up in device category? My assumption is this is either an emulator or the app is available to download on web? It's not a lot of users, but any context is helpful :)